# Do functions which are not defined as async-safe, such as mmap(2), effect other async-safe functions called in signal handler?

Tags: c, signal-handling, async-safe

I am making a library which gets injected into processes and redefines some of functions, such as open(2) to do some tasks before calling real open(2). My library would call mmap(2). As open(2) is async safe, is it possible that someone using the library who called open(2) in signal handler and where my library also added a call to mmap(2) could make his call to open(2) go wrong?

UPDATED QUESTION:

```
void handle_sigint(int sig)
{
    int fd = open(“file”, O_RDWR, 0666);
    void *base = mmap(NULL, 20, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
}
```

In the above function, will the call to open(2) be effected because I called mmap(2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

If your substitute `open()` calls a function that is not async-signal-safe, then it is not safe for a signal handler to call your function.  That it has the same name and signature as a standard function that *is* async-signal-safe is irrelevant.  That it calls the replaced function or other async-signal-safe functions is irrelevant.  That the prospective signal handler's call to a function that is not async-signal-safe would not be a *direct* one is irrelevant.

**In response to the question update**: in the event that the function presented in the question is called as a signal handler, it has undefined behavior on account of its call to `mmap()`.  The details of that UB cannot be predicted, at least not from the relevant standards.  That's what "undefined" means.  There is no reason whatever to suppose that the actual and apparent effects of the `open()` call would be somehow protected from interference.  Nor the general signal-handling mechanism.  Nor anything else in the program.

The further you get from the locus of the UB, the less likely is any noticeable effect, and the more likely the OS is to contain it, but UB is not something to mess with.  In principle, it may manifest as any behavior or behaviors within the power of your computer to produce, such as wiping your disk, turning off your CPU fan, or mailing your password to hackers.

Comment: I have some more queries, I am updating the question a bit, kindly see to that too.

Comment: @Mihir, I have updated my answer, but please do not do that again.  It is poorly regarded around here to modify a question after you already have answers.

Comment: Got it, will remember from next time.

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely possible. Another conflict would be a mmap() running on main that gets interrupted by a sighandler, which calls open() which calls mmap() causing a mmap() reenter.

The big keyword here is "reentrant": any function you use in a sighandler must be reentrant. This means, the function only manipulates stack data or, if it manipulates global data or state, it must do so in an atomic manner. Atomicity is a terribly difficult achievement, which comes with even more  terrible side effects that must be handled (i.e. deadlocks, the need for rollback/restart behavior... If you have any experience with RDB's you should know). In this context, mmap() is the motherlode of trouble, since it doesn't only manipulate process static data, but cross - process static data.